# Apply Customized Image after PXE boot

Tags: windows, boot, pxe-boot, dism, wim

I am pretty new to DISM/WAIK etc. I am trying to implement pxe on my virtual machines (virtualbox), if worked fine later planning to implement in our production environment.

I was able to deploy PXELinnux, boot and load new windows 10 OS using the following link:

https://www.tecmint.com/installing-windows-7-over-pxe-network-boot-in-centos/

After the command line (wpeinit) as per the article using net use command I could load the regular OS (when I have the contents of new CD) and run the setup.exe.

However I am trying to install customized windows 10 iso image (has set of scripts,applications and GPOs) which does not has the regular setup.exe to load the OS. I found the wim file and tried to deploy the wim files using the DISM apply image command , but it always result in error 1: Incorrect function.

Can someone please help me figure out why I am not able to deploy the wim file using DISM or guide me into the path if we have any other method to deploy customized windows 10 image ?